# Last time/the last time. Usage of the article

Tags: definite-article

> Last time I read a story about...
>   The last time I read a story
>   about...

Is it acceptable to use "the last time" (with *the*) when speaking about the previous occasion, one in a row: "The last time I read an interesting story", "The last time we talked about elephants"?

(Yes, I know that in sentences like "The last time I read that story someone knocked at the door", "The last time we met I saw that he hadn't changed much" the article is necessary.)

Comment: Either one is fine. The version with the definite article is slightly less informal.

Comment: Do you mean the difference between "Last time, I read a story about..." and "The last time I read a story about..."? Could you turn your examples into complete sentences? It might help.

Comment: Yes, exactly. 1. The last time we met I saw that he hadn't changed much. 2. The last time we met in a cafe. (=We usually meet twice a week, and last time we met in a cafe.) Is it acceptable to use "the" in the second sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct and idiomatic. There is an answer to a [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/477152/usage-of-definite-article-with-last-episode) on English Language & Usage that explains that the phrase without a definite article is acting as an adverb describing a superlative circumstance.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: I think the first version is correct only if it uses a comma after "last time". Or?

Comment: @virolino I don't believe a comma is needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Last time, I read a story about...

In this case, not using the definite article, the accent of the sentence falls on "I read a story", and "last time" has the meaning of "previous time". Please note the comma after "last time".

> The last time I read a story about...

The use of the definite article keeps the accent of the sentence on "last time". In this case, "the last time" has the meaning of "the last occurrence of several similar events": maybe it is not the last time when I read something (anything), but the last time when I read a story about... (TopicXZ) So it can mean previous, or it can refer to some older event - depending on the exact sequence of events.